# Asp.Net routing which redirects to homepage if url parameter is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have two routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{location}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

When user goes to main page, he has to chose two links:

```
<a href="/loc1/Products/index">Location 1</a>
<a href="/loc2/Products/index">Location 2</a>
```

Also I have `ActionFilterAttribute`, where I check for `location` parameter, and if url does not have it, i redirect users to main home page.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    string location = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["location"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) 
        && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "Home" 
        && !filterContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary 
        { 
            { "controller", "Home" }, 
            { "action", "Index" } 
        });
    }
        
    SessionUtils.SetLocationName(location);
}
```

Based on the `location` variable I will query different records from database, so when user does not provide any location in url, and tries to access `Products/index/5` I want them to be redirected to the main page where they have to choose location and click one of the links.
However I get error message:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Products/index

How should I properly configure routes, so that users would be redirected to main page if there is no location parameter in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined all answers and especially explanations I came up with this configuration

Route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultShort",
    url: "{location}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{location}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultHome",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "LandingPage"}
);
```

Some logic in `OnActionExecuting`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) 
    && cookie != null
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Values["location"])
    && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "LandingPage"
    && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "Home")
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "location", cookie.Values["location"]},
            { "controller", "Measurements" },
            { "action", "Index" }
        }
    );
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) 
    && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "Home" 
    && !filterContext.IsChildAction)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "controller", "Home" },
            { "action", "LandingPage" }
        }
}
```

If only location is provided, then it will use first route, which will redirect to the `Products` controller.

The second route will be used if all three `location`, `controller` and `action` parameters are matched in route. I have not provided default `controller` and `action`. This allows to use last route, when redirecting to `HomeController`.

The third route will have two parameters - `controller` and `action`, which allows me  to get to a default view in `HomeController`. Using `OnActionExecuting`  I'm redirecting to this default view and controller if it is not pointing to a `HomeController` and `LandingPage`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Default" route, which includes the location is the only route which will ever be hit. The `controller`, `action` and `id` params are all optional, so a request for something like `/Products/Index` will actually be caught by the your "Default" route and the `location` param will be given "Products" and your `controller` param will be given "Index" as a value. The `action` param will be the default of "Index", and the `id` param will be disregarded. Since you obviously don't have an `IndexController` with an `Index` action, you get a 404.

To differentiate the routes, you need need to make your "Default" route require some kind of hard-coded prefix, i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "location/{location}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then, the `/Products/Index` route will fall through to your "Home" route and be interpreted properly as a route to `ProductsController.Index`. Alternatively, you can apply route contraints to the `location` param, so it doesn't match *everything*, i.e.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{location}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { location = @"^(loc1|loc2)$" }
    );
```

Then, unless the first part of the URL matches either `loc1` or `loc2`, it will fall through to the "Home" route.

Comment: Using one `Default` route when I go to the main page I get `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`. Is it possible to go to main page without ptoviding location parameter?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a custom`route` before `Default` route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Location1Route",
   url: "{location}/{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

this will match your need.

Comment: What if I don't want to be dependent on `loc1` and `loc2'? The actual `location` will be pulled from DB  and HTML will be automatically renderred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered hard coded default and a fail-safe routes?

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
/*     Normal routing logic here     */
routes.MapRoute("FailSafe", "{*url}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}); // !=Last Line=!
```